# Append list of lists to dataframe display list errors

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Good afternoon,

I am looking for a way to append a list of lists into a dataframe as column but I am not getting the result I expected. I have a directory with 12 files and for each file , I want to put it in a dataframe with the correct header but so far what I am doing, put all the lists,  I get to the same column and I cannot change that.
The files are txt files and have mutliple rows. the small one has 200 lines and the long one has approx. 2020 lines.

```
path=r"C:\Use\Emmanu\Documents\tal\class\corpus"

files = os.listdir(path)

list_all = []

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)):
            f=open(os.path.join(path,file),'r', encoding= 'utf-8')
            #next(f)
            f = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
            list_all.append(f)
            
print(len(list_all)) 

print(len(list_all[7]))



df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(list_all).T.set_index(0).T

print(df.head(5))

df.columns = ['FR_IX', 'FR_IX_A', 'FR_IX_B', 'FR_OR', 'FR_A', 'FR_B', 
'MOT_IX' 'MOT_IX_A', 'MOT_IX_B', 'MOT_OR', 'MOT_A', 'MOT_B']
```

Result is like this and I cannot put each list in a column with the respective header.

```
12
431
0 ce qui me dérange, c’est le tout connecté, avec les ondes  \
1  Ce qui me dérange, c'est que tout est lié, ave...          
2  Ce qui me dérange, c'est que tout est lié, ave...          
3  Hélas, l'impression de violence, bien que très...          
4  Hélas, l'impression de violence, bien que très...          
5  Hélas, l'impression de violence, bien que très...          

0 Toujours en partant du fait que… donc, qu’il y a cette intelligence et puis on va pouvoir éliminer une partie de ce qui est régul. Maintenant, si ce n’est pas le cas… euh… je n’arriverais pas… Chez nous, je ne vois pas l’intérêt du produit.  \
1  Toujours à partir du fait que... donc, qu'il y...                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2  Toujours à partir du fait que... donc, qu'il y...                                                                                                                                                                                                 
3  Tout ça ne me donne pas envie d'utiliser un pi...                                                                                                                                                                                                 
4  Tout cela ne me donne pas envie d'utiliser un ...                                                                                                                                                                                                 
5  Tout cela ne me donne pas envie d'utiliser un ...
```

Comment: what are your textfiles? Tabular data? Just strings? Is each file one row or multiple rows? Does each line have the same amount of words? Please create a minimal working example

Comment: mutiple rows , they are txt files with multiple rows

Comment: what happens when you read the files directly with pandas `pd.read_csv('path_to_file')`? also to return a list of `.txt` files you can do `from pathlib import Path`;`files = [file for file in Path(r"C:\Use\Emmanu\Documents\tal\class\corpus").glob('*.txt')]`